# Join mysql ph pjson

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to display dateenregistrement from the table "listevoiture" , matricule from the table "voiture", marque from the table "voiture", nbrplacereserve from the table "voiture" , climatisation from the table "voiture"
For the where clause where "direction.villearrive= $villearrive" (Which must be a dynamic value entered by the user)
And finally encode the result in json format.

that is my php code :

[slectAll.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mh9C.png)

Comment: If I would make a list of what I want, It would have expended more time to it than you did on your question. Eitherway a question such as this is not welcome on [so]. Read [ask],

Answer (score 0):

```
 json_encode($array)
```

get the output result in array 
and use json_encode() function the result will be in json format